# How to rewrite url timthumb.php with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, timthumb

**Everybody**

**I have an url like this:**

sub.mydomain.com/crop/timthumb.php?src=http://another_sitelinks.com/images.jpg&h=150&w=150&zc=1

**How to rewrite to this url**
sub.mydomain.com/crop/150/150/hhcb3pu5lGFcinfq3sc8Pi7v85Vb5KGRq6KrlDdcttBH-RN91TvlOns7y4qRtjSu3A394x6qG6hdN1N68WVDm69H1Lg8lvJRXXKomYY72WF-Qieg9c8WCFfIiuW_tWCN

**Link demo :( but i dont know how they do that**
http://1anh.com/500/0/hhcb3pu5lGFcinfq3sc8Pi7v85Vb5KGRq6KrlDdcttARCeyGJ52j34f01EAkpOcCdy0AVDgq9jKEh31ro7bEsWHyC4TXb3ZiBT5egHc64au2ChOgYUbdshzrzIlZQqty

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Do a bit of research on REWRITE RULES.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not showing any effort.